# Gnosis safe: recurring transfers missing

Tags: gnosis, factory

I was checking the Reccuring Transfers Module from the safe modules repo and I saw an import called Module which is not actually present in the @gnosis.pm/safe-contracts npm package in the latest version 1.3.0. Should I revert back to 1.0.0 to use the Module contract?

I am going with the factory implementation. I'm sorry this might be a dumb question. I am trying to call the setup function on my newly created safe. But I am getting an error because your deployed implementation contract from Safe Deployments (unusable Safe) https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552#code has already set the threshold to 1 in the constructor and makes it not possible to call setupOwners because it reverts GS200(Threshold !=0). Should I create my own version of this contract and deploy it as my own Singleton Safe Deployment? or am I missing something that is obvious? Here is my code for your reference:
function deploySafe(uint salt, bytes calldata signature) public {
address safeAddress = _deployProxy(
i_safeImplementation,
msg.sender,
salt
);
address moduleAddress = _deployProxy(
i_moduleImplementation,
msg.sender,
salt
);

```
    bytes memory setupData = abi.encodeWithSelector(
        SETUP_MODULE_METHOD_ID,
        msg.sender,
        moduleAddress,
        bytes32(0)
    );

    bytes memory enableModuleData = abi.encodeWithSelector(
        ENABLE_MODULE_METHOD_ID,
        moduleAddress
    );

    safeAddress.call(
        abi.encodeWithSelector(
            SETUP_SAFE_METHOD_ID,
            [msg.sender],
            1,
            moduleAddress,
            setupData,
            address(0),
            address(0),
            0,
            address(0)
        )
    );
}
```

Hey @Germán | Safe , Thanks for the response. It still reverts an error when I try to create a new Safe using the SafeProxyFactory and call setup method using the intializer param. Here is my code for your reference:
bytes4 public constant SETUP_MODULES_METHOD_ID =
bytes4(keccak256("setupModules(address,bytes)"));
bytes4 public constant SETUP_SAFE_METHOD_ID =
bytes4(
keccak256(
"setup(address[],uint256,address,bytes,address,address,uint256,address)"
)
);
function _deploySafe(address moduleAddress,uint salt) internal returns(GnosisSafeProxy){
bytes memory setupModulesData = abi.encodeWithSelector(
SETUP_MODULES_METHOD_ID,
moduleAddress,
""
);

```
        return i_safeProxyFactory.createProxyWithNonce(i_safeImplementation,abi.encodeWithSelector(
                SETUP_SAFE_METHOD_ID,
                [msg.sender],
                1,
                moduleAddress,
                setupModulesData,
                address(0),
                address(0),
                0,
                address(0)
            ),salt);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.